Is it possible to keep TwinCAT in Runtime mode when the SSE: invalid operation exception appears?
I have some problem when used Tc Kinematic Transformation module with Motion control in TwinCAT 3. I try to control a 4-DOF Cobot by g-code and Kine-module. And sometimes, my input position is out of robot's range, that results in the SSE:Invalid operation exception and TwinCAT become Config mode, causing my motors to lose control (so dangerous). So, Is there any way for me to keep Twincat at runtime mode and report errors so I can restart the system?
I try to keep TC3 in Runtime mode, and if the kinematic transformation module encounters an exception, it only returns a message and exits the function, without stopping completely.

If you're using TwinCAT >4024 then you can catch exceptions.

I have discovered where the exception occurs. If the input to the inverse position kinematics exceeds the robot's operating range, a cosine formula returns a result outside the +-1 range, giving rise to a NaN result. I have put test conditions on all angle formulas to avoid this.
